# Changing the output of this python code in to a list?

Tags: python

The following python code gives me the different combinations from the given values.

```
import itertools

iterables = [ [1,2,3,4], [88,99], ['a','b'] ]
for t in itertools.product(*iterables):
    print t
```

Output:-

```
(1, 88, 'a')
(1, 88, 'b')
(1, 99, 'a')
(1, 99, 'b')
(2, 88, 'a')
```

and so on.

Can some one please tell me how to modify this code so the output looks like a list;

```
188a
188b
199a
199b
288a
```

Comment: Your output doesn't look like a list. Presumably you meant that the output should not look like tuples but simply *joined*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to convert the numbers to strings, then join the results:

```
print ''.join(map(str, t))
```

You could avoid having to convert if you made your *inputs* strings to begin with:

```
iterables = [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['88', '99'], ['a', 'b']]
for t in itertools.product(*iterables):
    print ''.join(t)
```

If all you want is to *print* the values together (and not do anything with them otherwise) then use `print()` as a function (by using the `from __future__ import print_function` Python 2 feature switch or by using Python 3):

```
from __future__ import print_function

iterables = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [88, 99], ['a', 'b']]
for t in itertools.product(*iterables):
    print(*t)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
iterables = [ [1,2,3,4], [88,99], ['a','b'] ]

new_list = [''.join(map(str, i)) for i in itertools.product(*iterables)]
```

Comment: Why the `list` in the map? Just do `map(str, i)`

Comment: @rassar: in Python 2, yes, not so in Python 3 (as `str.join()` works faster with list inputs).